# replace variables with texts by referencing external file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, scripting, python-3.7

I have a json file finaltext.txt which has variables like A00, A01 and 100 more. Each of these variables mean something which is stored in a different csv file SyslogEventID.csv
I want to add a code to my existing code to reference the external csv file and replace the texts maybe using text.replace() or something. Can someone help?
[image]

My existing code is just converting xml file to JSON file. The code is below

```
import xmltodict, json
from pprint import pprint

with open('DS7.xml', 'r') as myfile:
   obj = xmltodict.parse(myfile.read())
with open('finaldata.txt', 'w') as f:
   json.dump(obj, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

The contents of the json file look somewhat like this
[image]

Comment: *to my existing code* - show that code

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question and show a sample of the JSON file.

Comment: Can you explain (by way of example) what you mean by variables in a JSON file. JSON doesn't have the concept of variables. It does have keys and associated values.

Comment: I have edited the question with more info. My current code is just converting an existing xml doc to json doc. I didnt think its relevant for this question so didnt put that info in the first place. But I have now. I have also put up an image of how the json file looks like

Comment: Convert the csv file to dictionary for quick look up and then loop through your xml data which is a dictionary and replace value with value from csv file dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use PANDAS for making changes
but here you just need to reed the text and using replace function or easier way
you can also add loop and say
if x == y :
x == "z"

Comment: Can you help me with the complete code....